# Http vs https sitemap

Tags: sitemap

My site using nginx.

1. I didn't use ssl that time but i redirect www->http://
   a/When I registry my site in YOU in google webmasters I put 1 version of the site  y-o-u.cf (http://y-o-u.cf). I put sitemap with http
   b/ After that I add www property but I didn't add new sitemap to not dublicate content.

Is it good that I didn't put a sitemap with www ?

2. I add ssl connection. hhtp  redirect to https:// and www redirect to https:// using 301 redirection. all contenet is the same. Full redirection

Is it better to add property in google webmaster with https too?
Is it nessary to add sitemap with https when I am adding https property?
or
Is it better to remove http sitemap and to add https sitemap (google already indexed well all links) ?

3. What will happen with Google PR? Is my site will be better placed in google searching or will loose because now I have got 3 separate properties?

Thanks

Comment: Too many questions here. It also isn't clear what you are asking for some of them. Please try to limit the focus of this question to one topic and try to clarify exactly what it is you are trying to learn.

Comment: I saw that question before but answers are not good. Why?  Because Google said for every type make property. What's happen with sitemap ? Whare is better to put it.? And what's happen with indexing and search results.? If you wish to not duble the content where to put the sitemap and to improve searching results. This is the reason the same question to be asked on diffrent stages ?  I know enough for that but I am lookinhg for others who can  share their opinion with me.

Comment: From Google:For example, if you add the site http://www.example.com to Search Console, don't list site URLs in this format: http://example.com/home.html. Instead, use the full URL, such as http://www.example.com/home.html. If you have multiple variations of your site verified, such as http://www.example.com/ and http://example.com/), you should only submit URLs from your preferred version in your sitemap.

Comment: Preferred domain. To Google, http://www.example.com, http://example.com, https://www.example.com, and https://example.com are all different sites. Thus, sitemaps you’ve submitted for the site http://example.com won't be visible in the Sitemaps page of Search Console for http://www.example.com. To address this issue, make sure you've added all versions of your site then, tell Google your preferred domain and only submit sitemaps for the preferred one.

Comment: I 've got officeal answer from Google /NOT from you/:

Comment: Hello,

Need to add the sitemap to the preferred https:// version.  From the Search Console home page, go into the https site... and then the sitemap option.  Add it there...  

On the search console home page, you should have listed the following....

http://your-site.com                      ----(possibly shows just as....    your-site.com)
http://www.your-site.com              ----(possibly shows just as....    www.your-site.com)
https://your-site.com
https://www.your-site.com

You should remove the sitemap that was in the old http:// version.

steve